# Find duplicates in two files

Tags: text-processing, grep

I need to create script which read lines from one file and check if this line exist in second file. How to handle special characters in files like: ', " and \?

First file:

```
a.txt
aa
bb
cc
f
'f'
"g"
'h'
```

Second file:

```
b.txt
cc
dd
'f'
"g"
g
h
```

Command:

```
cat a.txt | xargs -I{} grep -w {} b.txt
```

Return:

```
cc
'f'
'f'
"g"
g  <- it shouldn't be there
h  <- it shouldn't be there
```

Expected:

```
cc
'f'
"g"
```

In my case last item (h) shouldn't be listed because this item doesn't exist in a.txt file. There is only 'h' (single quotes). How can I handle this in universal way to prevent unexpected situation in future?

Comment: can you add expected output separately for clarity? should `"g"` match `g`? are you trying to match only entire line? are you looking for `grep -xFf a.txt b.txt`?

Comment: @Sundeep answers in comments?

Comment: @Sundeep You are right g value shouldn't be there too. So your solution works in that specific case. I haven't defined what exactly I want to do.
Look at this:
cat a.txt | xargs -I{} sh -c "grep -x '{}' b.txt && do_something_more {}"
For each line which exists in other file I want to do some operation. How to pass this {} as is (with all quotes)? (I know this is another question)

Comment: Also has lot of answers here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373810/unix-command-to-find-lines-common-in-two-files

Answer (score 8):

This is what the `comm` utility is for.  Generally, you can do this one-liner to sort the input files and feed them to `comm`.  The `-12` options mean suppress the lines unique to files 1 and 2, showing only the common lines.

```
comm -12 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)

cc
'f'
"g"
```